# Why is my page not redirecting on success

Tags: php

I have some code that I was given; there is a $_POST variable (email) that shows as having content, yet when I test for it using *isset*, it fails.  I don't understand why it's failing; any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php 
session_start();

echo "POST variables<br>";
var_dump($_POST);

echo "<br><br>SESSION variables<br>";
var_dump($_SESSION);


$itemcount = isset($_SESSION['itemcount']) ? $_SESSION['itemcount'] : 0;
if ($itemcount == 0)  {
header("Location: "."error.php?msg=".rawurlencode("Please add items to your shopping cart before checking out."));
exit;
} 

echo "POST email value: ".($_POST['email'])."<br>";

if (!isset($_POST['email']))  {  //  <--  FAILS HERE
header("Location: "."error.php?msg=".rawurlencode("We did not find your information, please enter the needed information again."));
exit;
} 

echo "server request method: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
$_SESSION['shipname'] = $_POST['shipname'];
$_SESSION['shipaddress'] = $_POST['shipaddress'];
$_SESSION['shipzip'] = $_POST['shipzip'];
$_SESSION['shipcity'] = $_POST['shipcity'];
$_SESSION['shipstate'] = $_POST['shipstate'];

$_SESSION['paymenttype'] = "PayPal";
header("Location: "."thankyou.php");
} 

$shipname = isset($_SESSION['shipname']) ? $_SESSION['shipname'] : '';
$shipaddress = isset($_SESSION['shipaddress']) ? $_SESSION['shipaddress'] : '';
$shipzip = isset($_SESSION['shipzip']) ? $_SESSION['shipzip'] : '';
$shipcity = isset($_SESSION['shipcity']) ? $_SESSION['shipcity'] : '';
$shipstate = isset($_SESSION['shipstate']) ? $_SESSION['shipstate'] : '';

?>
```

And these are the results of the *echo* statements:

```
POST variables
array(11) { 
    ["lastname"]=> string(6) "dfgdfg" 
    ["email"]=> string(22) "kelliemmarsh@gmail.com" 
    ["city"]=> string(8) "van nuys" 
    ["fax"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["state"]=> string(2) "WA" 
    ["firstname"]=> string(5) "dfbdf" 
    ["address2"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["phone"]=> string(12) "509-555-1414" 
    ["zip"]=> string(5) "90266" 
    ["address"]=> string(14) "123 any street" 
    ["Continue"]=> string(8) "Continue" 
}
SESSION variables
array(8) { 
    ["cart"]=> array(4) { 
        [0]=> array(6) { 
            [0]=> string(6) "ch-002" 
            [1]=> string(6) "ch-002" 
            [2]=> string(0) "" 
            [3]=> string(0) "" 
            [4]=> string(0) "" 
            [5]=> string(0) "" 
        } 
        [1]=> array(6) { 
            [0]=> string(26) "Fish Wavy Stripe Turquoise" 
            [1]=> string(26) "Fish Wavy Stripe Turquoise" 
            [2]=> string(0) "" 
            [3]=> string(0) "" 
            [4]=> string(0) "" 
            [5]=> string(0) "" 
        } 
        [2]=> array(6) { 
            [0]=> int(1) 
            [1]=> int(2) 
            [2]=> string(0) "" 
            [3]=> string(0) "" 
            [4]=> string(0) "" 
            [5]=> string(0) "" 
        } 
        [3]=> array(6) { 
            [0]=> string(5) "10.99" 
            [1]=> string(5) "10.99" 
            [2]=> string(0) "" 
            [3]=> string(0) "" 
            [4]=> string(0) "" 
            [5]=> string(0) "" 
        } 
    } 
    ["itemcount"]=> int(2) 
    ["shipname"]=> NULL 
    ["shipaddress"]=> NULL 
    ["shipzip"]=> NULL 
    ["shipcity"]=> NULL 
    ["shipstate"]=> NULL 
    ["paymenttype"]=> string(6) "PayPal" 
}

POST email value: kelliemmarsh@gmail.com
server request method: POST
```

**UPDATE:  This is the revised code with all of the 'echo' statements removed:

```
<?php 
session_start();

$itemcount = isset($_SESSION['itemcount']) ? $_SESSION['itemcount'] : 0;
if ($itemcount == 0)  {
header("Location: error.php?msg=rawurlencode("Please add items to your shopping cart before checking out."));
exit;
} 

if (empty($_POST['email']))  {
header("Location: "."error.php?msg=".rawurlencode("We did not all of the required information."));
exit;
} 

else {
$_SESSION['shipname'] = $_POST['shipname'];
$_SESSION['shipaddress'] = $_POST['shipaddress'];
$_SESSION['shipzip'] = $_POST['shipzip'];
$_SESSION['shipcity'] = $_POST['shipcity'];
$_SESSION['shipstate'] = $_POST['shipstate'];

$_SESSION['paymenttype'] = "PayPal";


$shipname = isset($_SESSION['shipname']) ? $_SESSION['shipname'] : '';
$shipaddress = isset($_SESSION['shipaddress']) ?    $_SESSION['shipaddress'] : '';
$shipzip = isset($_SESSION['shipzip']) ? $_SESSION['shipzip'] : '';
$shipcity = isset($_SESSION['shipcity']) ? $_SESSION['shipcity'] : '';
$shipstate = isset($_SESSION['shipstate']) ? $_SESSION['shipstate'] : '';

header("Location: "."thankyou.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: You didn't define what "it fails" means. Fails to do what?

Comment: have you tried this `echo isset($_POST['email']) ? 'set':'notset';`  Also this is pointless `"Location: "."error.php?msg="` and simply says I lack the fundamentals of PHP to do it this way `"Location: error.php?msg="`

Comment: You can also do away with this `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` and just put an else there, because obviously if `$_POST['email']` isset then it must be a post request.

Comment: the reason why the redirect with `header("Location: ...")` is not working is, that you already sent a header by echoing something. Any header-redirection wont work afterwards

Comment: @Jeff - Bingo!  Id make an answer of that.  And add this in `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the page.  The question was baddy worded.  The way it's worded implies that the page is redirecting to the error page.  Which it obviously isn't, because we wouldn't see this output `server request method: ` which clearly we do.  A better wording is why is my page not redirecting on success.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix - I made it an answer. Could you explain the `ini_set('display_errors`,1)` to me, so that I can include it to the answer? My guess is: this will make php to show all errors, even if in production, right?

Comment: @Jeff - Yes that will show errors at runtime if they have them in  error_reporting (E_ALL), or such. It would be a warning or notice type as it doesn't stop execution.  I feel like it is a warning type.  It standard to leave error reporting on and display off.  So most times you can just turn display on and see what is going on.  It will be like `Warning: Cannot send headers. Output started on XX line ... `

Comment: I removed all the echos except this one which I added:I did the `echo isset($_POST['email']) ? 'set':'notset';` and first it displays 'set', then clears the page and displays 'notset'.  I don't understand why it does both?

Comment: it clears the page itself? or do you refresh?

Comment: nope, it clears the page itself after 1 or 2 seconds...  let me ask a question regarding echo before a redirection:  is that true even if the redirection is in a isset or if statement?  In other words, if the word 'echo' is anywhere before the redirection, it won't execute?

Comment: yes, that's true. not only with `echo`, but also with `print_r`, `var_dump`, or anything you send to the browser. Is there anything after the code you posted that could make the clearing of the page?? any html f.e.?

Comment: Thank you everybody that commented... I appreciate it... :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the redirect with `header("Location: ...")` is not working is, that you already sent a header by echoing something.

Any header-redirection won´t work afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
if (empty($_POST['email']))  {  
header("Location: "."error.php?msg=".rawurlencode("We did not find your information, please enter the needed information again."));
exit;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take out the `!`. That should fix it: if you enter a valid email you are negating true (which becomes false).

Keep in mind that when you use `isset()` it returns a boolean (true or false)