# passing a variable to another page while redirecting in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, redirect, runtime-error

I want to set a button that when I click on that it goes to another page.

below is my code:

```
if(sizeof($errors) > 0)
     {
       foreach($errors as $err)
       {
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$err');</script>";
       }
     }
     else
     {
       echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('finish');</script>";
       $newURL = "additional_info_sodur_card?id=" + $_GET['id'];
       header('Location: $newURL');

     }
```

Everything is OK and even to assure that it enters the else part I have written an alert which works.
The problem is that for header part it gives me an error like this:
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...
how can I solve this problem?
Can I use javascript with windows.location.href or other ways to be redirected to another page?
thanks for your response in advance

Comment: you can use sesssion or you have to pass status to newURL page

Comment: In your else block, comment out the echo line and see what happens

Comment: The shown error already tells you what to do.. you've got output before a header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my page not redirecting on success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688740/why-is-my-page-not-redirecting-on-success)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/

Comment: These didn't help me find the problem

Comment: I just found something about doing this:

if (headers_sent()) {
                die("Redirect failed. Please click on this link: <a href=".$newURL.">click</a>");
            }
            else{
                exit(header("Location: ".$newURL));
            }

It worked but I don't want the user to click on it to go to another page. I want the link to be self-clicked

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use JS redirect instead to avoid this.

```
?>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Your alert.');

    window.location = 'redirect_url';
  </script>
<?php
```

Hope this helps.